# lein ritz setup error

Tags: clojure, swank-clojure

I am trying to setup ritz/lein/emacs etc to create a clojure dev environment.

I installed `lein plugin install lein-ritz "0.5.0"` and added it to my project file. When trying `lein ritz` I get this exception:

> arash@azure:~/programming/onebreaker$ lein ritz
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at jline.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:69)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/eval_*init.class or leiningen/core/eval.clj on classpath:  (ritz.clj:1)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
>       at clojure.core$load$fn*_4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
>       at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
>       at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
>       at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
>       at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
>       at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
>       at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
>       at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
>       at leiningen.core$resolve_task.invoke(core.clj:208)
>       at leiningen.core$apply_task.invoke(core.clj:258)
>       at leiningen.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:329)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
>       at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
>       at leiningen.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:332)
>       at user$eval42.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
>       at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
>       at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:235)
>       at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
>       at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:270)
>       at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
>       at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:377)
>       at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:172)
>       at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
>       at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/eval_*init.class or leiningen/core/eval.clj on classpath: 
>       at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
>       at clojure.core$load$fn*_4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
>       at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
>       at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
>       at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
>       at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
>       at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
>       at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
>       at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
>       at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
>       at leiningen.ritz$eval68$loading_*4414*_auto____69.invoke(ritz.clj:1)
>       at leiningen.ritz$eval68.invoke(ritz.clj:1)
>       at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
>       ... 44 more

Can you helo me to resolve this?

Comment: Unless you're hellbent on swank, there's no need to use ritz. Leiningen 2 already comes with the `lein repl` command which will start an nREPL server for you.

Comment: Well, I want a sensible environment for my development. repl is nice, but swank is better. Do you have an alternative tool to run the code from your editor and jump to the function definitions? I am all ears

Comment: @Cubic Eh? ritz provides considerably better debugging facilities than plain nrepl (and recent versions include nrepl compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried leinigen2?
I'm using leiningen 2.0.0-review10 and have the following in my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file:

```
{:user {:plugins [
              ;;...
      [lein-ritz  "0.5.0"]
              ;;...
  ]}}
```

Running `lein ritz` results in:

```
user=> Swank server listening on local port 61428
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to try clojureone. Unfortunatily it doesn't support lein2 . I tried to port it, with little success. It seems for somereason lein2 doen't execute repl-init