# How to setup classpath for slimv and ritz

Tags: vim, clojure, leiningen, swank, slimv

I would like to resolve my problem for classpath.Could you tell me how to do?

## I can do the following.

#### I can eval (+ 1 1) in vim(slimv) by pushing ,e.

Then slimv display the followings.

```
user> 
(+ 1 1)
2
```

## However,I can not do the followings.

#### 1.When I eval the the following code in vim(slimv) by pushing ,e,

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.str-utils :only (re-split)])
```

#### 2.Slimv displays the following error.

; Evaluation aborted on java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/str_utils__init.class or clojure/contrib/str_utils.clj on classpath:

## My enviroment is the followings.

- macvim 7.3.754
- lein 2.0.0
- slimv 0.9.9
- ritz 0.7.0

#### project.clj

```
(defproject helloworld "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ritz "0.7.0"]]
  )
```

#### ~/.lein/profiles.clj

```
{:user {:plugins [
      [lein-ritz  "0.7.0"]
  ]}}
```

#### ref

[lein ritz setup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220319/lein-ritz-setup-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `clojure.string`?

```
(use '[clojure.string :only (split)])

(split "clojure8*)-6contrib&(*does^&$not*_^%exist^*#anymore" #"[^a-zA-Z]+")
=> ["clojure" "contrib" "does" "not" "exist" "anymore"]
```

BTW all `clojure.contrib` have been migrated to separated libraries http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have resolved my problem.
I did not know it.